# Multivariate normality in Confirmatory Factor Analysis - of items or factors?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, factor-analysis, psychometrics, confirmatory-factor

Quick question: when performing CFA with maximum likelihood estimation, does the assumption of multivariate normality apply to the items or to the latent factors?

Initially I thought it applied to the items, but considering the way the arrow points (that factor predicting the item score), I am now rethinking that.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Both. If latent common factors generating the manifest data are multivariate normal and the unique factors (which play the role of "errors") are also assumed normal then the manifest data cannot be but normal, too.